# In .NET is a custom user control considered backend or front-end or somewhere in the middle?

Tags: .net, frontend, backend

I know this maybe a too generic question but since a customer user control uses front end markup usually is that considered as a front end component or is it considered backend programming?
In other words how would you define a custom user control?

**UPDATE :**
In my deliniation of web programming there is a set number of components:

- Front end that is served upto the user
- Backend which is manipulated by the server and depending on logic can change the front end

Since a Custom User control can have this logic defined within itself I was wondering if it could be considered frontend in its strictest sense.

Comment: The words frontend and backend are [ill-defined and overloaded.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend), so you need to define what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom controls are part of the UI.
Thus, they are front-end.

In poorly-designed projects, they may also contain back-end logic.

Answer (score 1):

The user control is a client side (UI) and not considered backend programming or part of a business layer.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) a link to give more info